# Twitter Bootstrap float responsive container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, css-float

I need to float a `.container` for a tablet view, so how can I reverse this clear float hack within my media query? So that the `.container` can be floated

```
.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: 0;
  content: "";
}

.container:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understood the question, so to reverse the changes you made here within a media query use the CSS below to set it back to the initial.

```
.container {
  margin-right: initial;
  margin-left: initial;
  *zoom: initial;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  display: table;
  line-height: initial;
  content: initial;
}

.container:after {
  clear: initial;
}
```

Comment: Oh I get it so I just need to reset everything

Comment: yep, as long as the media query takes precedence.